# XML to HTML:Character entities encoding

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am doing `XML` to `HTML` Transformation and I need to convert some character entities. My XML file has Unicode values like `&#x00E8;` which I need to convert to its corresponding html value `&#232;`. Other entities also need to be converted respectively. Character mapping for each and every entity can be quiet difficult as there are many.

I am using XSLT 2.0. My output method is `xhtml`. And currently I am getting the actual characters (in the above case `è`) in my HTML code. Need help. My Saxon Processor version is `9.1.0.5`.

Comment: The hexadecimal references like `&#x00E8;` work in all browsers and other HTML user agents you can find these days, so why would you need to convert them? And if you are now getting the actual characters in HTML, that’s fine, provided that the character encoding is UTF-8 and declared that way, as it should.

Comment: E8 in hexadecimal notation = 232 in decimal notation. Conversion is possible, not too difficult and entirely unnecessary, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With normal XSLT processing Saxon will simply use an XML parser like Xerces or the version of Xerces the Sun/Oracle JRE comes with and once the parser has done its work and Saxon operates on its tree model there is no way to know whether the original input had a literal character like `è` or a decimal character references like `&#232;` or a hexadecimal one like `&#x00E8;`. 
And when serializing the result tree of a transformation you can of course use a character map to map characters to any representation you want but that will then happy of any `è` in the result tree, not only for ones resulting from hexadecimal character references in the input.
If you want to make sure all non-ASCII characters are serialized as character references then you need to use `xsl:output encoding="US-ASCII"`.
Saxon 9.1 also provides http://saxonica.com/documentation9.1/extensions/output-extras/character-representation.html to control the format.

But I agree with the comments made, these days having UTF-8 as the output encoding and then simply literal characters in the serialization of the result tree should not pose any problems.